# Mock private method with Mockito and PowerMock

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to mock private method with PowerMock like this

```
BalanceResponseGenerator balanceResponseGenerator = spy(new BalanceResponseGenerator());
when(balanceResponseGenerator, "getBalance",client.getParent(), request.getTerminal().getRetailPoint().getRetailNetwork(), result).thenReturn(new Balance());
```

But the real method is called, why it is so? what's wrong? I saw several examples all of them doesn't work for me. Explain please!

Comment: Have you put @PrepareForTest(BalanceResponseGenerator.class) above your TestClass?

Comment: Yes, of course I did it/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your when call is invoked on Mockito.when(..) rather. PowerMockito.when(..)

Proper examples is given at [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// We prepare PartialMockClass for test because it's final or we need to mock private or static methods
@PrepareForTest(PartialMockClass.class)
public class YourTestCase {
    @Test
    public void privatePartialMockingWithPowerMock() {        
        PartialMockClass classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new PartialMockClass());

        // use PowerMockito to set up your expectation
        PowerMockito.doReturn(value).when(classUnderTest, "methodToMock", "parameter1");

        // execute your test
        classUnderTest.execute();

        // Use PowerMockito.verify() to verify result
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest, times(2)).invoke("methodToMock", "parameter1");
    }
}
```